# How to use model Field name in foreign key attribute limit_choice_to

Tags: django, django-models

I have 3 Models
1.CustomUser
2.ABC
3.XYZ

CustomUser Model is an extended User Model.

ABC Model

```
    class ABC(models.Model):
        class_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
        profile_id = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser)


    class XYZ(models.Model):
        # This profile_id field is for knowing which user has created the following data
        profile_id = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser)
        processor = models.ForeignKey(ABC, limit_choices_to = {"profile_id": profile_id})
```

I want to add data in XYZ Model based on the profile_id field. The user who has created data in ABC Model can only add data in the XYZ model.
Suppose User A didn't add data in ABC Model. but trying to add data in XYZ Model. If there is no instance of USer A in model ABC it should give validation error through Model only.
I want to do this validation at Model Level. That's why I am using limit_choices_to.

Thanks in Advance.
If my question is not understandable. Please let me know

Comment: Why do you even duplicate the foreign key? `ABC` has that foreign key to `CustomUser` and `XYZ` has foreign key to `ABC`, hence `XYZ` does not need the same foreign key...

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat I want to know which user has created data in both the model. Suppose user A  has created an entry in the ABC table so he can create an entry in XYZ if he didn't created an entry in the ABC Table then he can't he has to first create an entry in ABC and then only he can go for XYZ